# Is there any way to change the video privacy on facebook by API?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to change the uploaded video's privacy in my code, but I couldn't find any API in Graph-API and also Facebook-SDK.

Answer (score 0):

No, if the post/video has already been uploaded then the API doesn't support changing its privacy level (at the moment).